# Is there a simpler way to convert DateTime? to DateTime.Date.ToString()

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a simpler way to convert DateTime? to Datetime.Date.ToString() than converting from DateTime? -> String -> DateTime -> String?

```
DateTime? timeReceived;

String dateReceived = timeReceived == null ? "" : DateTime.Parse(timeReceived.ToString()).Date.ToString();
```

Comment: Have you tried `?.` ? Eg `timeReceived?.Date.ToString()`. `?.` short-circuits the expression if the argument is `null` and returns `null`. To replace this with an empty space, append `?? ""`

Comment: Specifically, `timeReceived?.Date.ToString() ?? ""`. You could also write it long-hand, as `timeReceived == null ? "" : timeReceived.Value.Date.ToString()`

Comment: As an aside, I think `DateTime.Parse(timeReceived.ToString())` has to be the most imaginative alternative to `timeReceived.Value` I've seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` operator together with `??` (null-coalescing operator). `?` operator returns null if variable it is used with is null (in opposite to lack of this operator, which would throw null reference exception). I think you should use `string.Empty` to re-use predefined empty string and state explicitly what you want. Here's full example

```
string dateStr = timeReceived?.Date.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

There is also handy method `ToShortDateString` which you might want to use:

```
string dateStr = timeReceived?.Date.ToShortDateString() ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Why do you think OP should use `ToShortDateString()` rather than `ToString()`? That doesn't seem to be part of the question.

Comment: @canton7 I assumed OP wanted just date.

Comment: String dateReceived = timeReceived?.ToShortDateString.ToString() ?? ""; This is the easiest I found now. Result is: "02.11.2020". With .Date.ToString it is: "02.11.2020 00:00:00"

Comment: @MatsGausdal Please note the remark: I think you should use `string.Empty` to re-use predefined empty string and state explicitly what you want.

Comment: @canton7 Coming back to `ToShortDateString` - my intuition was right ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the null-safe operator [?.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) Eg `timeReceived?.Date.ToString()`. `?.` short-circuits the expression if the argument is `null` and returns `null`.

To replace a `null` with an empty string you can use the [null-coalescing operator ??](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), eg `somethingNullable ?? ""`. Putting it all together:

```
String dateReceived = timeReceived?.Date.ToString() ?? "";
```

You can also use `?[]` to access the element of a nullable array and `??=` to set a variable only if it holds a `null`. These two operators can simplify code quite a bit, and yet it's very easy to forget them. I keep rediscovering these all the time

Comment: This worked. I had not learned yet it is possible to use "timeReceived?" this way.